# Call Outlet of another view controller

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, controller, call

Hy Guys,
I have a MapperViewController

```
@interface MapperViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
 MKMapView *mapView;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@end
```

In the .m file I can add annotations on a MapView after creating an object (ofc I have a MyAnnotation class)

```
MyAnnotation *and = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
 and.name = @"name";
 and.subtitle = @"subtitle";
 and.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10.123,10.123);
 [mapView addAnnotation:and];
```

I have another object in another class called RootViewController where I added the values above.(ofc I have a Firma class)

```
    firmenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 Firma * aFirma = [[Firma alloc] init];
 aFirma.title = @"title";
 aFirma.boxOfficeGross = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 200000000];
 aFirma.summary = @"summary";
 aFirma.name = @"name";
     aFirma.subtitle = @"subtitle";
     aFirma.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10.123,10.123);
 [mapView addAnnotation:aFirma];
 [firmenArray addObject: aFirma];
 [aFirma release];
```

What I want to do is call the [mapView addAnnotation:aFirma]; within this view controller.
I have more functions in the MapperViewController which call "mapView", so it have to stay there.

MB someone of u can help me
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not try make *MKMapView* a member variable of your RootViewController?

Or, you are also welcome in Object-C to set a delegate hierarchy so that your RootViewController and MapperViewController can communicate in a parent-child way.